# How to run 32 bit eclipse in Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit machine?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed **Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit**. i am unable to run 32 bit applications like eclipse.I tried to install ia32-libs packages.But it shows there is no packages available.How to solve this problem ?

i have successfully installed ia32-libs by following steps in Ubuntu 14.04.But the same steps not working in Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo -i                                                             
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d                                          
echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
universe   multiverse" >ia32-libs-raring.list                       
apt-get update                                                      
apt-get install ia32-libs                                           
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ia32-libs-raring.list                    
apt-get update                                                      
exit
```

Comment: There are 64 bit versions of Eclipse available.

Comment: Actually i want to run both(32 bit and 64 bit) eclipse in ubuntu 16.04 64 bit machine.

Comment: You need a 32 bit JVM for 32 bit Eclipse.

Comment: You would also need a 32-bit GTK+ version.

Comment: I have installed 32 bit JRE only.But the problem is 32 bit applications cannot run in 64 bit machine directly.so we have to add 32 bit architecture support to the machine.we have install 32 bit libraries.How to install that libraries in Ubuntu 16.04 ?

Comment: You can check the answer of http://askubuntu.com/q/359156 At least you need to execute command: `sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386`. **i386** indicate the lib is 32bit. I don't know what libs are required, you have to try by yourself.

Comment: i have installed all the above architectures and added i386 support.but still unable to start my 32 bit eclipse in Ubuntu 16.04.i had the same scenario in ubuntu 14.04, but after installing ia32-libs i am able to run eclipse.But in Ubuntu 16.04 i am unable to install ia32-libs.

Comment: i have added ia32-libs installation steps.please find it and tell me the possible solutions if any.